# How to use the terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, sudo

when I type any  command the terminal asks for password and then when I write nothing show up .. how can I solve that ?

Comment: which command do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running a command with `sudo` at the beginnning, which means that it will run your command as the `root` user. This requires a password. It may look like:

```
[sudo] password for $USER:
```

If the characters don't show up, this is **NORMAL**, and is primarily provided as a security feature with `sudo`. Just type your password, and hit `Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

The password is actually being typed in, but is not visible to the user.

When the password is prompted from you, just type it in, press `Enter` and you've done :)

**Note** the characters are not visible to increase user security.